# Get the ratios by group in R

Tags: r

EDIT: I would like to add two additional columns: mean and range (see  below)

My data are as follows:

```
year  species  count
2020  chinook  10000
2020  chum     1450
2020  sockeye  600
2020  coho     1100
2021  chinook  8672
2021  sockeye  
2021  coho     10100
2021  chum     200
```

I would like to get the chinook to other species ratio for each year. In some years, species do not have count data, so I would like to just leave the outcome blank for those species.
I would then like to get the mean and range for each species across years.

The finished dataset I am looking for is as follows:

```
year  species  count  proportion  mean    range
2020  chinook  10000  1           1       1
2020  chum     1450   0.145       0.084   0.023-0.145
2020  sockeye  600    0.06        0.06    0.06
2020  coho     1100   0.11        1.274   0.11-1.164
2021  chinook  8672   1           1       1
2021  sockeye         NA          0.06    0.06
2021  coho     10100  1.164       1.274   0.11-1.164
2021  chum     200    0.023       0.084   0.023-0.145
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% group_by(year) %>%
  mutate(proportion = count / count[species == "chinook"])
```

Comment: Thank you @Gregor Thomas! I have added two additional columns for the desired output (see edit). Could you take a peak at the edit please? Thanks again.

Comment: What did you try and where did you get stuck? I'll get you started `... %>% group_by(species) %>% mutate(mean = {{your code here}}, range = paste(min(proportion), {{your code here}}, sep = "-"))`.

Comment: df %>% 
  group_by(year) %>%
  mutate(proportion = count / count[species == "chinook"]) %>%
  mutate(mean = mean(proportion[species])) %>%
  mutate(range = range(mean[species]))